# format validation doesn't work. why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, model

I have a little problem:

I have this in my model:

```
validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => /[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9\-_]*/i
```

This in my controller:

```
  def create
    @page = Page.new params[:page]

    if verify_recaptcha(:model => @page) && @page.save
      redirect_to @page
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

However, someone created [a page with a + in its title](http://wildptr.heroku.com/pages/C+). How can this happen? Is the RegEx wrong? I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting start and end matchers in your regex:

```
/^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9\-_]*$/
```

Otherwise it still matches if the + is at the start or end.

Comment: Sorry - doing a bit of searching I'm guessing that you're using rails 2.

Comment: I am using Rails 3. Oh, and the `^` and `$` did the job. You saved my website! :D

Comment: Sorry I messed up my edit.  However the problem is that you're not matching the start and end as with my new answer.

Comment: Weird that Rubular doesn't flag that.

Comment: Rubular was how I checked it!  The validation only wants to ensure that there is a match, not that the whole string matches end to end.  It's the job of the regular expression to define that.  If you try C+ in Rubular you'll see that there is a match (which the + isn't included in).  When you add the anchors then there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Nick has it almost right, instead of passing the :format to validates_presence_of, you need to add another validator:

```
validates_format_of :title, :with => /[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9\-_]*/i
```

Also, I'd shorten that regex a bit:

```
/[A-Z][\w\-_]*/i
```

You can use http://rubular.com to check the if your regex gives you the expected result.

Comment: I don't use `validates_presence_of` :)